# What is the default value to be given for a std::thread reference in Thread_Guard class

Tags: multithreading, c++11, raii, stdthread

I'm writing a class `Thread_Guard` as explained in the book *Concurrency in Action* at Listing 2.3 - Using RAII to wait for a thread to complete.

Below is the class

```
class Thread_Guard  
{  
    thread& gThread;
public:  
    Thread_Guard() : gThread(NULL) {};  
    explicit Thread_Guard(thread& t1) : gThread(t1)  
    {  
    }  
    ~Thread_Guard()  
    {  
        if (gThread.joinable())  
            gThread.join();  
    }  
    Thread_Guard(const Thread_Guard& gT1) = delete;  
    Thread_Guard& operator=(const Thread_Guard& gT1) = delete;

};
```

What is the value to be initialized for the reference to `std::thread` in the **default constructor**? I will be calling it from `main` like below. Where `MyInt` is a sample class I have written.

```
int main()  
{  
    int a = 100;  
    MyInt customInt(a);  
    thread worker(customInt);  
    Thread_Guard(worker);   
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The original version of `thread_guard` does not contain a default constructor; probably by design. It would be interesting to see the use-case motivating your question (perhaps there's an alternative?).

However, if you do want to do this, you could simply store a `thread *` in the class object, make the default constructor set it to `nullptr`, and have the destructor check this first:

```
class Thread_Guard
{   
    thread *gThread;
public:
    Thread_Guard() : gThread(nullptr) {};                                                                                                                                                               
    explicit Thread_Guard(thread& t1) : gThread(&t1)
    {
    }
    ~Thread_Guard()
    {   
        if (gThread && gThread->joinable())
            gThread->join();
    }
    Thread_Guard(const Thread_Guard& gT1) = delete;
    Thread_Guard& operator=(const Thread_Guard& gT1) = delete;

};
```

Comment: Thanks Ami Tavory for the answer :), It's just a doubt I got, what would be the default value to a thread reference in this case.